# Why does send return a bool

Tags: payments

When withdrawing funds from a smart contract send returns a boolean

```
function withdrawFromContract(uint amount) onlyOwner returns(bool success) {
    if(amount > this.balance) throw; // not enough money
    if(msg.sender.send(amount)) {
        LogWithdrawal(amount);
        return true;
    } else {
        throw;
    }
}
```

under what circumstances would send return false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<address>.send(amount)` would return false on failure to send `amount`. For example, if you did not have the line above which checks `this.balance` to be greater than `amount`, you could accidentally try to send more than the contract has access to, and in that case, the function would return `false`.

You can gain a little more insight reading the solidity docs [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related).

Comment: is that the only reason it would return false?

Comment: It would only return false on failure to complete the `send`. There could be other reasons for the function to fail besides lack of funds, but none that are immediately obvious to me.

Comment: Thanks, I'l mark this as accepted in a few minutues, I have to wait for the timelimit to expire

Comment: If the recipient is a smart contract, the `send` could run out of gas or the recipient could revert.